# Are dageishim kalim absolute?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, pronunciation

When a word starts with one of בגדכפת and the previous word ends in a vowel, usually the בגדכפת letter does not get a dageish unless it falls into one of the exception categories.

What happens if you mispronounce a word that falls under this category and ends in a consonant, and then you notice your mistake right away?

Options:

- Repeat the word as normal, without the dageish.  This sounds a bit strange, since the reason it loses the dageish is because it's connected to the previous word.  In this case it's not, but maybe we should pronounce the word as the mesorah dictates anyway.
- Repeat the word, but with a dageish in the first letter.
- Go back to the word before it so you can pronounce it properly without the dageish and still have it sound right.

  - But what if the word before is Hashem's name?  Should you say Hashem's name again for the sole purpose of making the dikduk come out right?  (Example: [Isaiah 54:5](http://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.54.5?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))

The same question applies to a word that starts with a dageish chazak because of דחיק or אתי מרחיק.

Comment: Are you asking about _leining_? _Davening_? Something else?

Comment: @Daniel Any of the above.  Why, do you see a reason why it would make a difference?

Comment: @Heshy did the mistake change the meaning of the word?

Comment: @Heshy I'm just trying to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Note יהוה ends in a Yud and wouldn't be followed by a Rafeh BGDKPT (eg. [Exo 13:15](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.13.15))

Comment: @user6591 TTBOMK these Degeishim can never change the meaning of words. (FTR some Rishonim think even non-meaning-changing mistakes are correctable.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't realize that Yud counts as pronounced.  Thanks for finding an example!

Comment: In מי כמכה the midrash takes notcie in the difference between the first no-dagesh and the second with-dagesh. The meaning is the same but the fact a word when pronounced correctly has no dagesh has a meanging in the PaRDaS. IMO,pick 3 if possible, else 1.

Comment: @Zeev The Midrash is noting the exception. Degeishim Kalim are definitely not absolute, as is evidenced by the Ten Commandments (is it Lo Tignov or Lo Signov?). The real issue here is if when repeating a word have you introduced a extra pause (essentially the same as changing the Trop) and then does that pause change the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought of the case of the aseret hadibrot, but from that (and the וילך ראובן pasuk) you could argue that the trop are not absolute either.  Maybe they are still absolute, just there are two complementary readings for these particular cases, like kri uchtiv

Comment: @Heshy Indeed, Trop is also not absolute. It's a system of punctuation. If you want to punctuate things differently, you change the Trop. The parsing is the same, even if you contextually have to describe it differently.